# Stablishing connection using UA Expert with security policies

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have been able to connect to the server using UA Expert as anonymous, using username and password, and certs. However, I am not quite sure how to connect to the endpoints using basic256sha256 security policy with Sign and SignAndEncrypt Message Security Modes.

[image]

This is how those two end points appear in UA Expert
[image]

What do I need to do to make the connection? I am also quite new to OPC UA and milo.

This it the error I get when trying to connect to Basic256Sha256 - Sign and Encrypt URL (First secure channel)

[image]

And this is the error I get when trying to connect to last URL (https-uabinary)

[image]

I tried authenticating using username & password and certs. Same error!

Comment: Can you update your question to include more information, like what happens when you select the secured endpoint and try to connect?

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you very much for the quick response. I have updated the question with more details. Thanks...

Comment: Hi Kevin, any thoughts on this?

Comment: Have you trusted UaExpert's client certificate on the server side?